# Are there any free tools for designing encounters or traps?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools, encounter-design, tool-recommendation, traps

I'm trying to design a module and I was wondering if there were any free or open source encounter or trap designers for D&D 4e

Mostly I just like something that lets me fill in the blanks and produce some kind of nice print out.

Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend [Masterplan](http://www.habitualindolence.net/masterplan/) as it's a fantastic encounter and scenario planner well integrated with 4e mechanics. I've used it myself quite successfully.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed, I had seen it before but forgot about it.